# Is it the same write the iPhone and iPad app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have a question about the objective C. I am writing the iPhone application and I want to app which can also run on iPad. Is there are some change do I need to do? As I set the element in code rather than using the Interface builder. Do I need to reset the x,y,width and height for the application? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run exactly the same app developed for iPhone on the iPad. However, it will not use the full screen of the iPad. Look at the Facebook app for instance, you can zoom it but it doesn't look very nice. If your goal is to run an iPhone app on the iPad, you don't have to bother much. If you want to really support iPad in your application you should implement a separate UI for iPad and this is supported in XCode. The iPad has of course a larger screen but also some additional layouts and controls that make apps look great on the iPad.

Have a look at http://developer.apple.com they have more information about this.